# How can I use sed to modify a line of a configuration file?

Tags: sed

My configuration file has the following format

```
[general]
setting1=true
setting2=value2

[ssl]
setting1=sadfsdf
setting2=sdfadsfkljasdf
```

How would I change setting 1's value to false? If I could just delete the line, I could use the response from [another question I asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/379290/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-a-specific-stanza-in-a-config-file).

Answer (score 7):

try something like:

```
sed -i -r 's/setting1=true/setting1=false/' /path/to/your/file
```

or if you want to replace *all* instances of a setting try something like this:

```
sed -i -r 's/setting1=.*/setting1=false/' /path/to/your/file
```

Comment: I think you really should spend some time and learn a bit of regular expressions.   `sed` makes a great deal of use on them... and you can easily answer your own questions if you spent 15 minutes learning regexp.

Comment: Just to be sure you should match the start of line (unless your configuration variable names are prefix free): `s/^setting1=.*/setting1=bar/`